# Get value of textbox using jquery inside of Razor Foreach loop

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, razor

I have a div like this in my view, keep in mind this is inside of a @foreach loop in my razor view:

```
<div class="testClass">
    <input type="text" class="tempLabel" /> 
                    <input type="button" data-value=@(item.ID) class="testButton3" value="Test Alert" />
</div>
```

This javascript works:

```
$(".testButton3").click(function () {    
     alert($(this).attr('data-value'));                
        });
```

what I want to do is get the value of the textbox inside of my tempClass class when I click the above button.  I tried this but it does not work:

```
$(".testButton3").click(function () {    
         alert($(".tempLabel").($(this).val()));               
            });
```

Is this possible?  Perhaps it is not possible to get the value of the textbox inside a foreach loop....

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They might be multiple elements created by foreach. you can try .prev() method of jquery to reach exact textbox like below.

```
$(".testButton3").click(function () {    
     alert($(this).prev(".tempLabel").val();                
        });
```

Comment: You missed a parenthesis but this worked great!  Did not know about the .prev method (or the .next for that matter).  Great idea!

Comment: Welcome buddy .. That was a typo :)

Comment: Interesting to note that the two elements need to be inside of a class (testClass in this example) for this to work.

Comment: they must be at same level in hierarchy not under same class :)